# Umbraco Child MVC Application (Virtual Directory) - Could not load file or assembly Umbraco.ModelsBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm trying to deploy a custom, pure ASP.NET MVC app as a Virtual Directory "Application" under my Umbraco 7 site root. However, I always get the following YSOD error:

```
Server Error in '/DemoApp' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Umbraco.ModelsBuilder' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've also tried this from scratch to eliminate as many variables as possible. Here are the repro steps:

1. Created a brand new empty ASP.NET solution/project
2. Added the UmbracoCms nuget package (7.4.3)
3. Built the solution
4. Setup my IIS Site - "UmbracoDemo" with host name `umbraco-demo.local`
5. Browsed to `http://umbraco-demo.local` and ran the Umbraco installer

**NOTE: So far everything works as expected. I can log into the back office or browse the new Umbraco site..**

6. Created a new ASP.NET MVC application in a new VS solution called "DemoApp"
7. Built the new solution and ran it immediately with IIS Express -- the MVC app works correctly
8. In IIS Manager, I right-clicked my UmbracoDemo site and added an "Application" called "DemoApp", pointing it to the DemoApp MVC project directory
9. Added "~/DemoApp" to the `umbracoReservedPaths` setting in Umbraco's web.config
10. Browsed to `http://umbraco-demo.local/DemoApp`

Again I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Umbraco.ModelsBuilder' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

---

**Additional info:**

I don't think this is specifically related to ModelsBuilder. Just to see what would happen, I added this to my "DemoApp" web.config:

```
<assemblies>
  <remove assembly="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder" />
</assemblies>
```

Now the error message says:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So naturally, I tried adding:

```
<remove assembly="UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
```

But this had no impact, the error remained. And in another instance the error mentioned a different assembly instead of `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter`.

Answer (score 3):

I got this working by adding ~/api/ to:-

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/bundles, ~/api/" />
```

And then wrapping the following web.config sections of my parent umbraco app with the location tag:-

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
```

and

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
```