# Umbraco root site and ASP.NET MVC application in subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to setup a ASP.NET MVC application in a subdirectory of an Umbraco site. This new ASP.NET MVC application will run as a virtual application. 
For example, the Umbraco site is located at www.domain.com, and the other MVC application is located at www.domain.com/app.

I'v tried thise approach: [Umbraco Child MVC Application (Virtual Directory) - Could not load file or assembly Umbraco.ModelsBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853115/umbraco-child-mvc-application-virtual-directory-could-not-load-file-or-assem)

It works but there are some issues.

1. All images placed in the /media section will no longer render.
2. The /umbraco route fails, so we cannot access the CMS.

There is not any error message, just 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred' when I try to go to the '/umbraco' route.

Can you, please, tell me what is wrong or how to create application in a subdirectory of Umbraco as a virtual application?

The Umbraco version is 7.7.1.

And one note - the Umbraco is hosted on the Azure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that web.config settings are inherited. Therefore, if your Umbraco installation is in the directory /wwwroot and your virtual application is in /wwwroot/app, the web.config settings for your Umbraco installation will be inherited. And it can cause major problems.

You'll see some recommendations to wrap your Umbraco's `<system.web>` and `<system.webServer>` sections in a `<location>` tag. The problem, as you've mentioned, is that doing so prevents inheritance from some Umbraco subfolders, which breaks things such as /media and the /umbraco CMS portal.

Therefore, you'll need to override problematic web.config settings in your /app's web.config file. Here's what worked for me:

1. Between the `<appSettings>` tags, add `<remove key="owin:appStartup" />`.
2. In your `<system.web><membership><providers>` section, be sure to add `<clear />` as your first child. Doing so removes the inherited Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider. Because if ASP.NET can't find that class, it'll present you with an exception.
3. Similarly, in your `<system.web><roleManager><providers>` section, add a `<clear />` as your first element for the same reason.
4. In your `<system.web><compilation><assemblies>`, add a `<remove assembly="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder"/>`. Otherwise, your app will barf when it cannot locate that assembly.
5. In , add `<remove name="UmbracoModule" /><remove name="ClientDependencyModule" /><remove name="ImageProcessorModule" />`

That should do it. But the gist is to find Umbraco assemblies that are loaded in your Umbraco's web.config file that are Umbraco-specific, then remove them in your virtual application's web.config to prevent inheritance and the resulting "assembly not found" errors.